# Hibernate: How to update Child record in OneToOne relationship (Superclass Subclass Inheritance)

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

Following is our entity:

```
Core {
}

External extends Core{
}
```

Core has named query for fetching "select c from Core" which returns Core object only as it does not have record in external. If it has External record then we also get External data and able to typecast core to External.

But if only Core is received then We are not able to typecast it to External i.e

```
External e = (External) core; //Not Possible as no record in external
```

Requirement: I want to update the same in hibernate managed "core" entity with External data and merge it to database.

Could anyone suggest how to achieve the same? (No @OneToOne annotation is used)